# Pasar SQL query (join & group by) a Sequelize

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelize.js, sequelize

¿cómo puedo interpretar esta consulta de SQL a Sequelize?

```
SELECT category.name, COUNT(productos.category_id)
FROM category
LEFT JOIN productos
ON productos.category_id = category.id
GROUP BY category.name;
```

Intenté esto, pero no funciona:

```
db.Producto.findAll({
include: [{ association: "category" }, { association: "maker" }]
})
.then(response => res.json(response)
```

Comment: In Spanish please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La tabla principal, según tu query, es `category`. Por lo que quizá necesites modificar un poco más tu consulta. Asumiendo que `sequelize` es la instancia de sequelize que tienes en el código.

```
db.Category.findAll({
    attributes: ['name', sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('Productos.category_id'))],
    include: [
        {
            model: Producto,
            attributes: [],
            required:false
        }
    ],
    group: ['Category.name']
}).then((categories) => {
    // result
});
```

En cuanto a estructura, eso podría servirte, sólo revisa que los nombres de los modelos estén bien. Aquí te dejo la documentación de los métodos que se usan:

- [sequelize.fn()](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#fnfn-args-sequelizefn)
- [sequelize.col()](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#colcol-sequelizecol)
- [Left Join](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html) (required: false)

Comment: Muchas gracias, me queda claro el ejemplo :)